Error trying to load System.Text.Json, Version=8.0.0.4
I have recently started to get this error when publishing my project. It compiles fine and runs fine on my local machine, but when I publish it to our staging server it produces this error. My project doesn't use System.Text.Json and I have removed it from the project via NuGet but the error still prevails. I am aware there are similar questions on here regarding this but none of the answers given are of any help. I'm using .NET 8. Already spent 2 days on this so any help would be greatly appreciated. I did try installing version 8.0.4 from NuGet but that didn't help either.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=8.0.0.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. 

UPDATE: For anyone else suffering with this problem, the issue arised because I had installed .NET 9. Note that my project was still using .NET 8.
To fix it add a global.json file to your route directory with the following content
{
  "sdk": {
  "version": "8.0.400",
  "rollForward": "latestFeature"
  }
}


Please provide a [mcve], otherwise we'll all just be guessing.

Have the same problem but it is hard to create a reproducible example. Everything went good until we explicitly set reference to system.text.json 8.0.5 because up to 8.0.4 was vulnerable. Everyone is capable of building locally, but when we build on our server with msbuild, we got this error :/

Actually check this if you are using .NET 9
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/43339#issuecomment-2344233994
Add a global.json in your solution folder with content { "sdk": { "version": "8.0.400" } } to force use .NET 8 SDK if your project still targets .NET 8

@Alkampfer This is actually what I ended up doing and seemed to fix the problem
